# Unable to assign value to NSCollectionView objects from delegate in Mac OSX / Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

My Mac OSX NSViewController is acting unexpectedly. I've done UICollectionViews on iOS dev, but stumped with this.

I have created a CollectionView Item class that handles the class that has outlets to NSImage and NSLabel:

```
import Cocoa

class CollectionViewItem: NSCollectionViewItem {

@IBOutlet weak var messageThumb: NSImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: NSTextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.wantsLayer = true
        view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.lightGray.cgColor
        view.layer?.borderColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
        view.layer?.borderWidth = 0.0
    }

}
```

The delegate is listed below and is triggered, and the number of items is correct - so I know the delegates and sources are right. It correctly pulls the Item View (I believe - though, it says "`object (null)`") from running "po item" in debuging in console

```
<Konch.CollectionViewItem: 0x6000001232a0>{represented object: (null),
view: <NSView: 0x600000123200> (frame {{0, 0.5}, {65, 87}}), selected:
NO}
```

but the related NSImage and NSLabel always come up as nil and I can't assign values to it....

```
extension RecordViewController: NSCollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: NSCollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.messages.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ itemForRepresentedObjectAtcollectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

        let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewItem", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewItem
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.item]

        guard let collectionViewItem = item as? CollectionViewItem else {return item}

        collectionViewItem.dateLabel.stringValue = "SADFDF"

        return item
    }

}
```

Am I mis-understanding something?

**UPDATE**:
Here is my xib
[image: xib file]

And IB outlets on CollectionView VC

[image]

**UPDATE**:

Answering @El Tomato, I am naming the related class in the Xib

[image]

Comment: Where do you register the `CollectionViewItem` nib ?

Comment: @WarrenBurton, added an image of my Xib, but I am not manually "registering" it anywhere in code. I didn't see it in Ray's tutorial or sample code, so I figured it wasn't needed (confusedly so). https://www.raywenderlich.com/145978/nscollectionview-tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Got it working, but still don't fully understand why.

I suppose in Mac OS development you do not need to create outlets from your objects to the class. Instead I connected my outlets to the "Objects" -> "Collection View Item" as shown below.

[image]

For some reason, without any IBOutlet references, I could set my image view and label from within the class as shown here.

[image]

Never needed to register the xib or anything.

Still confused how the whole system is working together.